# Copy a specific piece of XML to a string based on an Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following from a XIB file

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center"      contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OGN-yD-hzb">
                <rect key="frame" x="4" y="21" width="36" height="36"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="36" id="Sgc-0Z-H82"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="36" id="WLV-12-NHf"/>
                </constraints>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
                <state key="normal" title="fdf">
                    <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
                <state key="highlighted">
                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
            </button>
            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="abV-ij-rke">
                <rect key="frame" x="276" y="21" width="36" height="36"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="36" id="ps5-Pb-Ebc"/>
                </constraints>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
                <state key="normal" title="Button">
                    <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
                <state key="highlighted">
                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
            </button>
```

I've already separated out the DestinationIds from the connections and the entire xib file has been loaded into an XDocument.

Is there a way that I can grab the specific button (with the children) with the corresponding ID? SelectSingleNode looks to be the way, but that returns null every time I pass in the attribute ID for the button.

Comment: Show the XPath you have used in SelectSingleNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least there are 3 different approaches to get specific `<button>` by it's `id` attribute. You can use `XDocument` combined with either LINQ to XML standard methods or `XPathSelectElement()` extension like so :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var xpathResult = doc.XPathSelectElement("//button[@id='abV-ij-rke']")
                     .ToString();
var queryResult = doc.Descendants("button")
                     .First(o => (string)o.Attribute("id") == "abV-ij-rke")
                     .ToString();
```

Or using older XML API, `XmlDocument`, as you mentioned about `SelectSingleNode()` :

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var result = doc.DocumentElement
                .SelectSingleNode("//button[@id='abV-ij-rke']")
                .OuterXml;
```

All worked fine to get specific button element markup when tested against the XML you posted.

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons = doc.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (var button in buttons )
{
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) button).GetAttribute("Id"));
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) button ).InnerText);
}
var rect= doc.GetElementsByTagName("rect ");
foreach (var button in buttons )
{
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) button).GetAttribute("ID"));
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) button).InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement)rect).ParentNode);
}
```

try it